# How to ssh to remote web server without using a password

Tags: terminal, ssh, unix

I'm new to OS X.

As per title, I'm having trouble connecting to my web server through SSH.
My server accepts keys and we don't use passwords.
I've come from windows, and on windows I used PuTTY to connect to my server using a .ppk file generated using PuTTYGen.

On the Mac, I've generated using ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 and made a key.ppk file in ~/.ssh and pasted the contents of my Windows .ppk file into it.

I also made a config file with the following contents...

```
Host domain.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.ppk
  User username
```

When I try to connect, Terminal prompts me for a password (why?) then when I enter nothing and press ok it fails with message

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong will be great!
Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: What is key.ppk? Are you sure that's an 2048-bit RSA private key?

Comment: Have you remembered to copy the public key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server? (Also, try giving the `-v` flag to `ssh` to get some more information.)

Comment: The .ppk file is PuTTY-specific. It won't work with anything else. I've included instructions for converting it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## On Reusing Your Windows `key.ppk` File

The PPK file is a PuTTY-specific private key. It's not a portable private key that works with any ssh-based application. It just works with PuTTY. You need to convert it first. I've found some instructions for converting it to a proper public/private key pair [here](http://leadingedgescripts.co.uk/server-administration/how-to-convert-your-putty-ppk-private-key-to-a-normal-ssh-key-you-can-use-on-an-apple-mac/). You'll need to do this from your Windows machine.

That will give you a private key, `key.ssh`, that will work with ssh on your Mac. Put the `key.ssh` file in your `~/.ssh/` directory. Make sure the permissions are correct:

```
% chmod 400 ~/.ssh/key.ssh
```

And then you can use it with your `~/.ssh/config` file like so:

```
Host domain.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.ssh
  User username
```

If you no longer have access to your Windows machine you'll need to generate a fresh public/private key pair to use with your web server.

## On Generating a Fresh Keypair To Use With Your Mac

Honestly, this is the best way to go here.

Password-less authentication with shared keys requires that both machines have a piece of the shared/public key pieces. Here's a complete recipe for setting up a shared key authentication scheme with two servers. It's not really OS X-specific. It's ssh-specific.

These instructions assume *host1* is your Mac and *host2* is your web server.

Generate a shared key on host1 (the shared key will be `/Users/you/.ssh/webserver.pub` and the private key will be `/Users/you/.ssh/webserver`):

```
% ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/webserver
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in webserver.
Your public key has been saved in webserver.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
98:b7:fa:0f:0d:e7:7f:50:cc:9b:b4:57:db:8d:b4:03 ian@Ian-Chesals-iMac.local
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|             o   |
|       o    E * .|
|      o S .  = *=|
|       . *  . B.+|
|        o o  . o |
|       . . .  .  |
|      ..... ..   |
+-----------------+
```

Note: I didn't enter a password for the key because I don't want to have to use a password when I use the use.

Now you need to append the `~/.ssh/webserver.pub` public key to the `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on *host2*, your webserver.

```
% ssh user@host2 'mkdir ~/.ssh;echo '`cat ~/.ssh/webserver.pub`' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

For this to work you *will* need password access to the remote host. If you don't have this you can give `~/.ssh/webserver.pub` to someone who *does* have access to the box and ask them to append it to the `authorized_keys` file for you perhaps. Or do it from your windows machine where you still have access.

Now make sure your private key is safe on your Mac:

```
% chmod 400 ~/.ssh/webserver*
```

ssh can get complain-y if your private/public keypairs are world readable or writeable.

Finally, you can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file to invoke the right key combination when you try to ssh in to your web server:

```
Host domain.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/webserver
  User username
```

This will get you the password-less, keypair-based authentication you desire.

Comment: Ian, Thanks for this answer - Just put it into practice and it works perfectly!

Comment: @MattClarke awesome!